# JQuery make BootStrap DropDown menu open class Go Away / Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make my AJAX JQuery code to close the BootStrap dropdown menu after clicking on the link element that nested inside the dropdown menu,

***Note: I only want to close the dropdown that has the link I clicked on!!!***

This is the code snippet of my HTML :

```
<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">GPU<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <div class="custom-menu">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="list-links">
                <li>
                    <h3 class="list-links-title">Brands</h3>
                </li>
                <form id="gpu_form" action="create/" method='POST'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input name='manuf' value="amd" class="gpu_form_input">
                <input name='manuf' value="nvidia" class="gpu_form_input">
                <li><a href="#">AMD</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NVIDIA</a></li>
                </form>
                </ul>
                <hr class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

This is my AJAX CODE . IT IS NOT WORKING:

```
/*GPU FORM click on input event*/
                $('.gpu_form_input').on('click',function(event){
                    console.log('this.serialize=',$(this).serialize());

                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'findGPU/',
                        data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,data:$(this).serialize()},
                        success: function(serverResponse){
                            console.log('success, testing', serverResponse);
                            $('.placeholder').html(serverResponse);

                            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().toggleClass("open");
                            console.log('end of success action.');
                        }
                    })

                });
```

Basically once the ajax update the part of the home page, I want the open drop down to go away by removing the 'open' class from the bootstrap, apparently it is not going anywhere...

This makes me feel like a little kid being mad when he cannot assemble his Lego.

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().toggleClass("open");`? Isn't there only one dropdown menu there? Why not `$('.mega-dropdown').removeClass('open')?